# nginx serving from html instead of gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a nginx / gunicorn / django app I've set up following

https://medium.com/@_christopher/deploying-my-django-app-to-a-real-server-part-ii-f0c277c338f4

It works when I go to the main IP from the browser  (I got Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: admin/...) but when I go to /admin I got a 404. Nginx logs are as follows:

```
2019/07/05 00:30:28 [error] 13600#13600: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 186.190.207.228, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.62.118"
```

So it is trying to serve files from html/ instead of serving gunicorn, why?

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;    
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;} 

    location = /static/ {
        root /home/juan/site;    
    }
    location = /media/ {
        root /home/juan/site;
    }

    location = / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/juan/site/site.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting `listen 8000` and restart nginx, then visit 127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser. If it works that would mean you have another server listening on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `=` from all the Location directives except the first. That means exact match, instead of the prefix match you want.

```
location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;} 

location /static/ {
    root /home/juan/site;    
}
location /media/ {
    root /home/juan/site;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/juan/site/site.sock;
}
```